# operator expression vs direct call to built-in method in new style python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which tries to call **add** function on its object. 
Consider the following code :

```
class Test(object):
    data = "hello"
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('getattr: ' + name)
        return getattr(self.data, name)

>>> obj = Test()
>>> obj + 'world'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Test' and 'str'
>>> type(obj).__add__(obj, 'world')
AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute '__add__'
```

In new style classes,

```
(obj + "world")
```

is  equivalent to

```
type(obj).__add__(obj,"world")
```

So why am I getting different error in both these cases? 
I was expecting same error as both statements appear equal to me. I've started python few weeks ago. Therefore, I am unable to find which concept I am missing here.

Comment: the first error comes from the operand `+`, the second error comes from the object `Test`

Comment: Yes, first error comes from "+" but this "+" internally calls __add__ method  like this : type(obj).__add__(obj,"world") .  So  how these two are different? Btw, thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator is not entirely equivalent to `type(obj).__add__`. `+` also calls `type(other).__radd__` if the other method is not defined, and throws more descriptive errors when neither method exists. If you want to exactly emulate `+` as a function, use `operator.add`.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for the exact difference between these two approaches. Had it been indexing operation instead of addition, then how obj [index] would have been different from type(obj).__getitem__(obj,index)?

Comment: @geek In the case of indexing, the only difference is an extra error messages. For `+`, I believe that these are the only differences.